# How to remove multiple redundant indexes?

Tags: mysql, index, schema, index-tuning

I have a legacy app.
I wanted to find out which tables are the largest ones using [script from Percona blog](https://www.percona.com/blog/2008/02/04/finding-out-largest-tables-on-mysql-server/). It turned out some of my tables have indices that are larger than actual data by factor of 3 and more.
I've dumped schema off the MySql server and found that some tables have lots of what seem to be redundant indices.

Here's how one of the worst tables is created:

```mysql
CREATE TABLE `pictures_relations` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `pic_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `url_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'id урла, с которого файл был/будет скачан',
  `is_stub` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `item_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `module_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `item_type` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `is_file` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `is_hide` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `is_cover` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `image_only` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_custom` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `skip` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `order` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `author` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `add_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `is_hide` (`is_hide`),
  KEY `is_cover` (`is_cover`),
  KEY `add_date` (`add_date`),
  KEY `item_id_2` (`item_id`,`module_id`,`item_type`,`is_file`,`is_cover`),
  KEY `order` (`item_id`,`module_id`,`item_type`,`is_file`,`order`),
  KEY `item_id` (`item_id`,`module_id`,`item_type`,`is_file`,`is_custom`),
  KEY `pic_id` (`pic_id`),
  KEY `item_id_3` (`item_id`,`module_id`,`item_type`,`is_file`,`skip`),
  KEY `item_id_4` (`item_id`,`module_id`,`item_type`,`is_file`),
  KEY `pic_id_2` (`pic_id`,`skip`),
  KEY `skip` (`skip`,`pic_id`),
  KEY `stub_url` (`is_stub`,`url_id`),
  KEY `stub_skip_url` (`is_stub`,`skip`,`url_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6794944 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I can clearly see that indices `order`, `item_id`, `item_id_2`, `item_id_3` and `item_id_4` are mostly similar, but they differ a bit. Using convenience views for easily detecting redundant indexes from [this DBA.StackExchange answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/11705/66282) helps, but not much — it does show that `item_id_4` is redundant to all others, but doesn't help with splitting/merging them into more sane indexes.

The question is:
*Is there a Rule of Thumb to refactor these indexes into something sane, with less duplication?*

Like, if I have `idx1('a', 'b', 'c')`, `idx2('a', 'b', 'd')`, `idx3('a', 'b', 'e')`, then I have to make it into `idx1('a', 'b')`, `idx2('c')`, `idx3('d')` and `idx4('e')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The question cannot be answered without seeing the `SELECTs`.*

Here are some partial answers...

- The only obviously redundant queries are `pick_id` and `item_id_4`. The rule is simple:  If all the column(s) of an index are exactly the first column (s) of some other index, then toss it.  (Note: This applies only to non-unique indexes.)
- The next set of apparent duds are `(is_*)`.  These all seem to be true/false "flags".  The Optimizer won't use such (with rare exceptions).  It will, on the other hand, consider `INDEX(is_foo, ...)`.  That is a composite index starting with a flag.  (And, no, the low cardinality of the first column is *not* bad.)
- 5 columns in an index is pushing the max that it "should" have.  I would be tempted to keep *one* of the 5-column indexes starting with (`item_id`,`module_id`,`item_type`,`is_file`).  The ones I tossed would still be benefit, at some level, by the one I keep.
- Reordering the columns depends on what the `SELECTs` look like.  If the user can request "any" combination of columns to filter, then punt.  Well, not totally punt...  Make a few combinations of 2 or 3 columns.
- `INDEX(a,b,c)` is *not* the same as `INDEX(a,b)`, `INDEX(c)`.  Some queries benefit from one; some from the other.

See also: [*Cookbook on generating indexes*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using pt-duplicate-key-checker tool from the Percona Toolkit package.

```
pt-duplicate-key-checker —user=root —ask-pass —databases dbname
```

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT tab_left.TABLE_NAME, 
CASE 
WHEN tab_left.COLUMNS = tab_right.COLUMNS AND (tab_left.IS_UNIQUE = tab_right.IS_UNIQUE) 
THEN GREATEST(tab_left.INDEX_NAME, tab_right.INDEX_NAME) 
ELSE tab_left.INDEX_NAME END REDUNDANT_INDEX_NAME, 
GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT CASE WHEN tab_left.COLUMNS = tab_right.COLUMNS 
AND (tab_left.IS_UNIQUE = tab_right.IS_UNIQUE) 
THEN LEAST(tab_left.INDEX_NAME, tab_right.INDEX_NAME) 
ELSE tab_right.INDEX_NAME END SEPARATOR ', ') INDEX_NAME 
FROM (SELECT TABLE_NAME, CONCAT('`', INDEX_NAME, '`') AS INDEX_NAME, 
INDEX_TYPE, 
IF(NON_UNIQUE, 'NO', 'YES') IS_UNIQUE, 
GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('`', COLUMN_NAME, '`') 
ORDER BY IF( INDEX_TYPE = 'BTREE', SEQ_IN_INDEX, 0), COLUMN_NAME) COLUMNS 
FROM information_schema.STATISTICS 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_schema' 
AND TABLE_NAME = TABLE_NAME 
GROUP BY TABLE_NAME, INDEX_NAME, INDEX_TYPE, NON_UNIQUE) AS tab_left 
INNER JOIN (SELECT TABLE_NAME, CONCAT('`', INDEX_NAME, '`') AS INDEX_NAME, 
INDEX_TYPE, 
IF(NON_UNIQUE, 'NO', 'YES') IS_UNIQUE, 
GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('`', COLUMN_NAME, '`') ORDER BY IF(INDEX_TYPE = 'BTREE', SEQ_IN_INDEX, 0), COLUMN_NAME) COLUMNS 
FROM information_schema.STATISTICS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_schema' 
AND TABLE_NAME = TABLE_NAME GROUP BY TABLE_NAME, INDEX_NAME, INDEX_TYPE, NON_UNIQUE) AS tab_right ON tab_left.TABLE_NAME = tab_right.TABLE_NAME 
AND tab_left.INDEX_NAME != tab_right.INDEX_NAME 
AND tab_left.INDEX_TYPE = tab_right.INDEX_TYPE 
AND CASE WHEN tab_left.COLUMNS = tab_right.COLUMNS 
AND (tab_left.IS_UNIQUE = 'NO' OR tab_left.IS_UNIQUE = tab_right.IS_UNIQUE) THEN TRUE 
WHEN tab_left.INDEX_TYPE = 'BTREE' AND INSTR(tab_right.COLUMNS, tab_left.COLUMNS) = 1 AND tab_left.IS_UNIQUE = 'NO' THEN TRUE 
ELSE FALSE END 
GROUP BY tab_left.TABLE_NAME, REDUNDANT_INDEX_NAME;
```

Comment: Welcome on the DBA SE! Note, *this is not a code snippet sharing site*. It is Q/A site. "Write this code for me" questions are offtopic and disliked, and also "here is the code" answers.